# .NET Open Source Package Manager

Tags: nuget, openwrap

Hornget is gone, are there any other package managers like hornget that you can download the trunk versions of NH3 / FluentNH together?

Manually putting the two together is tedious and from what i can tell neither Nu or OpenWrap have the two trunks together :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Package Management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642212/net-package-management)

Comment: NuGet now seems to have a package for NH3 Beta 1/Fluent. Yay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horn being dead only means that it's not being developed anymore, however what it was able to do 5 months ago it can still do now. [The bits are still there](http://github.com/dagda1/horn_src), you can still use horn as a tool to build NHibernate 3 + Fluent NHibernate.

Or you can also get the combo [here](http://www.tigraine.at/2010/09/06/untangling-the-dependency-ball-windsor-nservicebus-caliburn-fluent-nhibernate-in-one-package/).

Comment: What I didn't want to have to do was build my own package. I meant that the Hornget website is gone, it was handy for just jumping on and grabbing the package(s) I needed. 

I found http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2009/10/29/the-horn-project-bringing-quot-apt-get-install-quot-to-net-projects.aspx tho which will help me figure out hot to build Fluent myself.

For now I've grabbed Fluent from the combo you linked to. Thanks.

Comment: @user456813: thing is, you either wait for the project maintainer to update their dependencies, or you do it yourself. If you do it yourself, I'd rather do it using horn than manually.

Comment: Thats fine if you know how to do it yourself. But a lot of those tools use NAnt, Git, and other things I haven't had a chance to even look at yet get familiar with. Coupled with the fact theres no decent up to date documentation on how to use those things makes it just as difficult. Thats why it's easier to just download the binaries and use them. Updating those binaries in a project only really happens when theres a particular bug fix you require or new functionality.

Comment: @user456813: if you use horn you don't need to know anything about using nant, msbuild or git. Horn takes care of that for you. Also, *using* nant to compile a project doesn't require you to *know* nant since you only call nant, not write a nant script.

Comment: Okie dokie. I'll have to get it up and running this weekend and have a play around. It will be handy to have projects up to date, but for now you've allowed me to press on. :) Thanks.

Comment: @user456813: it's certainly not trivial, but you can always ask here on stackoverflow for help.