# Add VS project that belongs to a different TFS Team project as a "link"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a solution for `Application X`.  `Application X` uses a shared library `Library Y`. `Library Y` is contained within its own project under TFS, separate to that of `Application X` (same server though, and both are available locally).

How can I add `Library Y` to the solution for `Application X` such that any changes made to `Library Y` will be correctly handled by its TFS project and wouldn't be added to the solution for `Application X`.

I believe their is similar functionality for single files using `Add as link`.

Comment: [NuGet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3642212/147211)?

Answer (score 0):

First let's differentiate between 2 things, there is a shared library and a shared source, shared library is not added to the solution, but shared source is added, because in a shared library, you just need the dll (Assembly) you don't need the source at all, you will not gonna edit it, but shared source will cross development across many project, so you gonna edit and develop on it.